# When adding to MYSQL database, apostrophes change to &#39; and are backslashed

Tags: mysql, database

I recently switched to a new server and now when I add new topics to my forum, apostrophes become `&#39;` as they enter the database, while the apostrophes get backslashed.

**For example:**

Mike's website becomes: `Mike\'s website`. While in the database it becomes: `Mike\&#39; website`.

I have checked to see if magic_quotes is on via php.ini -- it is off.

I have spent days troubleshooting, with no available reason why.

Strangely, when I use `&#39;` which creating the topic in my forum, it returns an apostrophe! I am assuming there is somewhat of a language problem. My forum is programmed to use UTF-8, and so is the database.

I checked database entries before the switch, and oddly, they would get recorded as apostrophes ' and not as `&#39;` ... Like it should. I know I could use striplashes(), but I don't want to since it worked properly without them before!

What apache/mysql settings are causing this to occur?

Furthermore, the characters < > also become html code characters.